# MongoDB docker compose is unable to create users

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to create a docker-compose file for MongoDB after checking out multiple examples on the web and this is my configuration. However after executing **docker-compose up** command, when trying to login using any of the below credentials in Compass at **localhost:37017**, I am getting the error:

```
UserNotFound: Could not file user "dbAdmin" for db "admin"
```

Folder structure

```
mongo [directory]
    docker-entrypoint-initdb.d [directory]
        mongo-init.js
    mongo-volume [directory]
    docker-compose.yml
```

**docker-compose.yml** content:

```
version: '3'
services:
    mongoDB:
        image: 'mongo:latest'
        container_name: 'app-mongo'
        environment: 
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=dbAdmin
          - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=TtUBhMjOIfeV
          - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=admin
        volumes:
          - ./docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.js:ro
          - ./mongo-volume:/data/db
        ports:
          - '37017-37019:27017-27019'
```

**mongo-init.js** content

```
let admin = db.getSiblingDB("admin");

admin.createUser({
    user : "appAdmin", 
    password: "TtUBhMjOIfeV",
    db: "admin",
    roles: [
        { 
            role: "clusterAdmin",
            db: "admin"
        },
        {
            role: "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            db: "admin"
        }
    ]
});

admin.createCollection("users");

let adppDBName = db.getSiblingDB("appDBName");

appDBName.createUser({
    user: "appOwner",
    password: "EtMxw6ZY9jiG",
    db: "admin",
    roles: [
        {
            role: "readWrite",
            db: "appDBName"
        }
    ]
});

appDBName.createCollection("users");
```

Answer (score 0):

You created a user named `appAdmin` but are apparently trying to use a user named `dbAdmin`.

Comment: I tried logging in with all the users mentioned above. None of them are apparently created

Comment: Well, the code you provided definitely won't work, so you may consider revising it.

Comment: I do hope you understand the whole concept of posting doubts on Stackoverflow.
Anyways, how do I do it?

Comment: I am suggesting you fix the clearly obvious deficiency in your attempted solution to your problem before asking for assistance. You may of course wait for someone to do all of the work for you and provide you with a finished product, but that person won't be me.

Comment: I looked for the "clearly obvious" deficiency in my code but couldn't find it. If I had, I wouldn't be posting this question in the first place. If you can point it out to me I'll be grateful, otherwise keep your 'high' stance to yourself, it does me no good.

Comment: With one of the comments deleted this exchange makes less sense, but yes, please do continue investigating without me.

Answer (score 0):

had a very similar issue.

seems the volumes were creating the issue in my case.
once i deleted the folders that were being mounted from my local, [ in this case `./mongo-volume` ] to the mongo containers `/data/db` directory.. it worked out.

**but just a reminder my project was in dev phase so deletion did not effect much**